# Querying for a date constraint

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsdate

I've done research on this question and thought I found the answer which makes sense but it's not working so i'm not sure if I'm making a silly mistake.  I want to query for data that is created in the past week, month, year,..etc.  I looked at my data already uploaded to parse and to test it out, I wanted to query for the data from the past 5 days.  For some reason, it finds 0 objects when there should be five objects created after August 8th.  When I switched to lessThanOrEqualTo it found all 9 objects even though there's 4 objects created before August 8th.  Any clarity on this. Thanks

```
NSDate *then=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-7200];
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"urinationAmount"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:then];
urinationDataArray=[query findObjects];
NSLog(@"Objects in Array:%i",urinationDataArray.count);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html), you shouldn't manually do calendar calculations.

Quote from the same document says:

> NSDate provides the absolute scale and epoch for dates and times, which can then be rendered into a particular calendar for calendrical calculations or user display. To perform calendar calculations, you typically need to get the component elements of a date, such as the year, the month, and the day. You should use the provided methods for dealing with calendrical calculations ***because they take into account corner cases like daylight savings time starting or ending and leap years***.

So five days ago should be something like this:

```
NSCalendar * currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

[dateComponents setDay:-5];//five days ago

NSDate * fiveDaysAgo = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:now options:0];
```

You can check [NSDateComponents Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003642) for further calendar units that you can use for your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will not give you five days ago:

```
NSDate *then=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-7200];
```

You should do:

```
NSDate *then=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1 * (86400 * 5)];
```

There are 86,400 seconds in a day.

Comment: Oh jeez thank you, I was multiplying 24*5*60 instead of 60*60*24*5. I knew it was something small